# How can I do a zoom effect to a button?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I want to know If it is possible to do a zoom-transition to get Inside a Button, where are more Buttons to find? Like there are some Main theme buttons and I want to get to the sub themes with other Buttons. And the Main theme buttons are dissolving after a Zoom Transition.
I need this Effect Inside one of My webpages.

Is this possible with js and/or CSS/html?

Comment: you can get this with any number of frameworks such as bootstrap, or just implement with JS or CSS, have you tried googling this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using transform

Eg.

```
.button:hover {
transform: scale(1.5);
}
```

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_zoom_hover.asp